# How to display a view for the tab?

Tags: wpf, view, tabs

I have a collection of Tabs in my main View Model. Every Tab pepresented by a class with several properties:

```
class SettingTab : ISettingTab
{
    public string Name { get; }

    readonly UIInfo UIInfo;
    public Type TypeView => UIInfo.TypeView;

    public Func<IViewModel> ViewModel => UIInfo.ViewModel;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public SettingTab(string Name, UIInfo UIInfo)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.UIInfo = UIInfo;
    }
}
```

}

How can I display a particular view when selecting a particlular tab?
Can you please say what should I add here

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
        TabStripPlacement="Left"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Next time, instead of describing your data models, show their implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TabControl` displays a list of `TabItem` elements, the tab headers, and the `TabControl.SelectedContent`, that references the `TabItem.Content` of the selected item, as the actual tab content.
By default the `TabItem.Content` is the `DataContext` of the `TabItem` - in your case it's the `Tab` data model.
This means, the `DataTemplate` of the `TabControl.Itemtemplate` and the `TabControl.ContentTemplate` share the same `DataContext` by default.
If you want to change the this default behavior, e.g., make a particular property on this `DataContext` as the `TabControl.SelectedContent`, you must specify this binding in the `TabControl.ItemContainersStyle`.

For example, if each of your `Tab` data item has a `Tab.ViewModel` property that you want to display as the `TabControl.SelectedContent`, then bind the `TabItem.Content` property to this `Tab.ViewModel` data property. Additionally, you have to define a `TabControl.ContentTemplate` for the data type of the `Tab.ViewModel` property to define the layout for the `TabControl.SelectedContent`:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
  <TabControl.Resources>

    <!-- Implicit DataTemplate for TabControl's content -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TypeOfTheViewModelPropertyOnTheTabType}">
      ...
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.Resources>
  <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">

      <!-- Make the property value of 'Tab.ViewModel' the DataContext of the content -->
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ViewModel}" />
    </Style>
  </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Tab}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```